# CSS background color not changing

Tags: css

This is my super simple code and the background color isn't changing for some reason. I know that the external CSS is linked correctly because the text color of h1 is changing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>random</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="randomnezs style.css">
<style>


body{
    background-color: black !important;
}
h1 {
    color: red;
}
<style>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Typically you don't want spaces unescaped in URLs. Make it `randomnezs+style.css` or `randomnezs%20style.css`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Div with background image and no content not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310808/div-with-background-image-and-no-content-not-displaying)

Comment: I'm afraid not.

Comment: There is no `body` element in the HTML at all. How would you see the background color on something that is not present?

Comment: I only showed you the CSS, there is a body element in the html.

Comment: There's a `<html>` tag there... Please show us a [mre] of the code that reproduces the situation. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to make it runnable here.

Answer (score 0):

Because your body height is 0, you can set some height for it.

```
body{
    background-color: black !important;
    height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>random</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="randomnezs style.css">
<style>


body{
    background-color: black !important;
    height: 10px;
}
h1 {
    color: red;
}
<style>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Hien Nguyen.

i tried and it didn't change anything.